# Static function linker error

Tags: c++, static, linker

I have followed these instruction:

[is it possible to define the static member function of a class in .cpp file instead of its header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911126/is-it-possible-to-define-the-static-member-function-of-a-class-in-cpp-file-inst/6911190#6911190)
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-plus-plus/c-plus-plus-static-functions.html

However, my example give gives me linker error:

```
"Example::Value", referenced from:
Example::PrintA()     in Text.o
Example::PrintB()     in Text.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my `Text.h` file:

```
class Example
{

public:

    static int Value;

public:

    static void PrintA();
    void PrintB();

};
```

And my `Text.cpp` file:

```
void Example::PrintA()
{

    cout << Value;

}

void Example::PrintB()
{

    cout << Example::Value;

}
```

How do i fix this, so that i am able to print the value from both `PrintA` and `PrintB`? I am on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Xcode 3.2...

Comment: Did you intialise static variable correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting class static members definition into cpp file -- technical limitation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409428/putting-class-static-members-definition-into-cpp-file-technical-limitation)

Comment: @iammilind Thank you. Just now i read the post. ^^ And if i understand correctly, i not only need to declare the `static` variable, i also need to tell the linker about it through initialization within the file where it is to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the static variable in cpp file.

```
int Example::Value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! ^^ I am still very much leaning how to correctly use `static`, primarily so that i can utilize get instance.